# Redirected Drive Assignment

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, drive-letter

In DOS there was a command that would allow you to redirect drives to another letter, for example:

```
ASSIGN  D: = C:
```

This would allow apps looking at `C:\` to be direct to `D:\`.  Is this possible in Windows 7?

Comment: there is `mklink` which might serve if you have a specific issue you were hoping to resolve

Answer (score 1):

ASSIGN has been depreciated since DOS 6.0 (although still available until 6.22) because it was dangerous and could seriously mess up your data.

SUBST can be used as the replacement in most cases and is available in Windows (even Window 10) too.
(For the situations where SUBST isn't an exact replacement: Those are the situations where ASSIGN is dangerous and, in case of Windows, able to completely trash the content of your hard-disk.)

Answer (score 0):

No, take a look: http://www.computerhope.com/assignhl.htm

> Availability
>
> The assign command is an external command file named assign.com and is
>   available in the below Microsoft operating systems as assign.com.
>
> MS-DOS 2.0 - 6.0, 6.2, 6.22

Any users using Windows 95 or above should not use this command and consider using [the subst command](http://www.computerhope.com/substhlp.htm) as a substitute.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers suggest `subst`, but you should be aware that:

1. assignments are not maintained over restarts, so you need to make
   the command run on system start-up, but this could still cause
   problems on commands executed before the start-up command runs;
2. `subst` is an external command (`subst.exe`), so in the start-up
   folder you can run it directly, without using `cmd /c`; and
3. disc management does not know about the substitution, so you can
   reassign a drive letter to be the same as a substituted drive, with
   unpredictable consequences.

An alternative is to share `C:`, and make `D:` a network drive which points to the `C:` network share name. If you make the mapped drive persistent, you need not worry about restarts; and disc management will not offer a network drive when you reassign a drive letter.